# how to make transition delay in bxslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, bxslider

Is there any solution to put slider delay with `onSlideBefore` or any other alternative to fix caption animation ?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/ffp3h/)

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    onSlideBefore: function(){
      $("figcaption").css({
        "top" : "100%"
      });
    },
    onSlideAfter: function(){
      $("figcaption").css({
        "top" : "0"
      });
    }
  });
```